# AWS RDS Mariadb Federated/Connect

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds, federated-table

I believe this is a firewall rule problem. Therefore, I believe that the issue is finding out what the public IP address of the RDS is. I don't see that anywhere on the RDS interface.

I have two AWS RDS MariaDB databases. I can connect to both without a problem. From the command line, I type:

```
mysql -u me -p db1.cet4jwf1l8xu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

I connect no problem. I can also connect to db2 without a problem.

In db2, I want to remotely access a table from db1. I have done this with both Federated and Connect. I get the same error: Can't connect to server, timed out. The syntax for each is pretty much the same:

```
create table testtable engine=federated connection='mysql://me:test@db1.cet4jwf1l8xu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/mydb/demo';
```

It sits for a while and then comes up "can't connect." I can switch to engine=connect and get the same timeout error.

In the incoming security rules for db1, I have port 3306 open to everywhere. So, I assume it shouldn't be blocking it. Inside db1, user me is set to host '%', which I believe means 'anywhere'. So, I don't think that is the problem either. I'm not sure what else could keep it from connecting when I can connect from a basic CLI on multiple other servers.

Comment: It's like the outbound traffic that is blocked.

Comment: @mustaccio I agree. It appears that outbound traffic from the RDS is blocked even though the security rule is all ports open to all destinations. I know that federated systems is disabled for MySQL, but it doesn't state it is disabled for MariaDB. I bet it is, but not noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article regarding [how to install federated plugin on mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-federatedx/#installing-the-plugin). And as far as I know, anything related to the server's config file will be available and configurable using RDS Parameter Groups.

I checked on my AWS account for the `plugin_load_add` directive and found it, but it isn't modifiable, so this means that RDS for mariadb doesn't support federated engines yet (or load that plugin).

[image: rds-param-group-mariadb-10-6]

Seems like currently RDS only supports for PostgreSQL functionality similar with federated engines i.e. [foreign data wrappers (FDW)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/federated-query-support-for-amazon-aurora-postgresql-and-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/).